# Is it possible to pre-heat an application while building a docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I wonder if it could be possible to save a warmed up application as an image and then use it to produce containers that are ready to process requests without the cold-start penalty. For example, a Java Spring microservice

Comment: Do you mean like with a snapshot of the RAM mounted in?

Comment: @ValerijDobler yes

Comment: Docker doesn't really care what the image's `CMD` is, so if you have some way to create a runnable binary with the state you need preloaded, Docker can run it.  That is, there's nothing really Docker-specific here.